# TypeError<anonymous> javascript error

Tags: javascript, sentry

We use sentry.io / ravenjs to track JavaScript errors. We see a huge number of errors with the following details:

```
document.getElementsByClassName.ToString is not a function

    <anonymous> at line 1:33
```

The details for the users / devices generating this error are very similar:

```
browser: Chrome 59.0.3071 (100%)
device: Samsung (100% / different models)
OS: Android (100%  / different versions)
```

Different users are generating the error but we have no idea how to simulate or solve it. The error is not reported in any other browser, device and os. Does anybody have any thoughts on how to solve this.

Update: As pointed out the reported error is ToString not toString which would make more sense. Since this error only occurs on a specific device/browser it seems unlikely the problem is with an undefined property or function. If this was the case then the error should also occur on other devices / browsers.

The text ToString cannot be found in our own JavaScripts or 3th party JavaScripts.

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName` is a function that runs in the browser,
`document.getElementsByClassName('class')` like such. Error is definitely being reported by browser but developer might have applied a try catch block so the error is not being thrown.

Comment: It's not `ToString` it's `toString`  But why you want toString of getElementsByClassName I have no idea.

Comment: I'm not certain the [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) object returned by getElementsByClassName has a `toString` method (as pointed out above `ToString` is definitely not a standard method)

Comment: I agree it is strange the reported error is ToString in stead of toString. However if this is a problem the error would occur in other browsers too. But it does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an issue with the browser, https://github.com/SamsungInternet/support/issues/56

Answer (score 1):

When you want to get an element by its class name, you have to use:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('yourClass');
```

However, this would give back the functionality of "document.getElementsByClassName" and how to use it, which parameters to use etc.

```
document.getElementsByClassName.toString();
```

If u want to get a string of your html element, you have to use this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('yourClass')[0].outerHTML;
```

Comment: The error only occurs on a samsung mobile device with Chrome 59.0.3071. If the problem was in a faulty function shouldn't the error occur on all/more devices?

Comment: Its not really an error, its more a warning. You could take any html related function, like "document" and add whatever to it like "document.blabla", it shouldnt crash your program and should only say "undefined". If you would add "()" to it, it would try to look for a existent function and give you an error, since it probably doesnt exist.